# How to make a category of irreducible representations a monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, monoidal-categories, kac-moody-algebras

Consider the category $\mathcal O$ for a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. As I understand it, we can define such a category whenever $\mathfrak g$ has a triangular decomposition. So $\mathfrak g$ can be for example a semisimple Lie algebra, or an affine Kac Moody algebra, or the Virasoro algebra.

We can construct Verma modules as quotients of the universal enveloping algebra, and they are objects of $\mathcal O$ [1,2]. So are their tensor products and their quotients.
In particular, all the highest weight irreducible representations $L(\Lambda)$ are in $\mathcal O$, since they are quotients of Verma modules.
This means that we can construct a category of irreducible highest weight representations as a full subcategory of $\mathcal O$. Let's call this category $C$.

**My Question:**
How can I make this category $C$ a monoidal category? (What tensor product can I define?)
Notice that the usual tensor product does not work, since the tensor product of irreps is in general not an irrep.

---

[1] Kac, V. G. (1990). Infinite-Dimensional Lie Algebras. Cam-
bridge University Press, 3 edition.
[2] Kac, V. G., Raina, A. K., and Rozhkovskaya, N. (2013).
Bombay lectures on highest weight representations of infinite dimensional
Lie algebras, volume 29. World scientific.

Comment: Frankly, I don't think you can, but maybe that is because I have trouble visualizing tensor products other than the standard one. But here is a simple toy model. Finite dimensional irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ are usually labeled by their dimension because there is exactly one in each dimension. This nicely illustrates a problem with your construction: naively the the tensor product of the $m$ and $n$ dimensional reps can only be the unique $mn$-dimensional one, but this likely doesn't have the right morphisms to make all the axioms work. It should be easy...

Comment: ...to check this. But then again I write 'naively' because the requirement $\dim (V \tensor W) = \dim(V)\dim(W)$ perhaps only follows when you require some nice behaviour w.r.t the forgetful functor to vector spaces and perhaps not directly from the definition of tensor category itself. I'm not sure.

Comment: More general: irreducible representations have very very little morphisms between them: only the zero morphism if they are unequal and only liner multiples of the identity morphism if they are (see under Schur's lemma). This might be a problem with the definition of monoidal category

Comment: Also, why would you want this? It is like saying: can't we define a new multiplication on prime numbers so that we don't need those annoying composites? I do sort of agree that composites are annoying, but if you define a new multiplication on prime numbers it will probably something like $p_m * p_n = p_{mn}$ (where $p_m$ is the $m$'th prime) which doesn't give you anything new in terms of multiplication while killing off all the nice info on addition...

Comment: @Vincent The reason is because I am working with the specific case of Kazama Suzuki models (which are a certain type of coset models), which provide highest weight irreducible representations of the Virasoro algebra, and I want a monoidal category of these representations because I want to compare this category with another category (which physicists conjectured to be closely related to my category) which is itself monoidal...

Comment: @Vincent Your observations are good, though, and maybe I should lose hope.

Comment: That full subcategory is the equivalent to the category with objects being weights $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*$, with $\operatorname{Hom}(\lambda, \mu) = \{0\}$ if $\lambda \neq \mu$, and $\operatorname{End}(\lambda) = \mathbb{C}$. Probably the only sensible tensor product on this category would be to define $\lambda \otimes \mu = \lambda + \mu$?

Comment: @Joppy But the problem is: given a highest weight irrep $V_\lambda$ and a highest weight irrep $V'_\mu$, how am I sure that there is (or how can I construct) a highest weight irrep with highest weight $\lambda+\mu$? Direct sum and tensor product of $V_\lambda$ and $V'_\mu$ of course don't work...

Comment: There is a bilinear map $V(\lambda) \times V(\mu) \to V(\lambda + \mu)$, defined by sending $(v, w)$ to $v \otimes w \in V(\lambda) \otimes V(\mu)$, and then using the canonical projection $V(\lambda) \otimes V(\mu) \to V(\lambda + \mu)$. The projection is canonical since there is a unique summand of $V(\lambda) \otimes V(\mu)$ isomorphic to $V(\lambda + \mu)$. I think that this bilinear map is usually called the "Cartan product", but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: A geometric version of this construction is to take line bundles on the flag variety $X = G/B$. There are line bundles $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$ and $\mathcal{L}_\mu$ whose spaces of sections are $V(\lambda)$ and $V(\mu)$ (or maybe their duals, I can't remember the conventions). The representation $V(\lambda + \mu)$ is then realised as the space of sections of $\mathcal{L}_\lambda \otimes \mathcal{L}_\mu$.

Comment: @Joppy Those are very useful comments, thank you. You can write it in an answer if you'd like. I still have to confirm that this tensor product really respects all the axioms for monoidal category.

Comment: The thing is, I think the category is so simple that knowing anything about representations is irrelevant. If you fix a dominant integral weight $\lambda$ and consider what the functor $\lambda \otimes (-)$ should do, on objects it is clear (it is $\mu \mapsto \lambda + \mu$), and on morphisms it should be clear too, since there are really only two possibilities. Either the morphism is zero, so its image under $\lambda \otimes (-)$ is also, or the morphism is a scalar endomorphism of $\mu$ with itself, in which case you should get a corresponding scalar endomorphism of $\lambda + \mu$.

Comment: @Joppy I agree with the morphisms part, but it is not clear to me that the tensor product on objects *has* to be addition...

Comment: @Joppy Your comments mentioning the Cartan product was important for my Master thesis. It would have taken me a while to find that that was an option otherwise. I would like to mention you (your real name) in the the thesis because of this. Contact me (see my profile) if you want.

Comment: @Soap Don't worry about it, I'm glad this helped you with your problem.

Comment: @Joppy The Cartan product seems not to work in the case of $Vir$ after all, since highest weight irreducible representations are infinite dimensional, and so we have no guarantee that the tensor product decomposes in such a way that there is a unique summand isomorphic to $V(\lambda + \mu)$.